# How to improve/replace my download function to Excel file in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, asp.net-mvc-3

The source data is in SQL Server 08. Currently my method works fine by returning upto approx 10-20k rows of data and outputting it in excel2007. However my problem is occassionally the dataset can be very large at about 5 million + rows. How do you achieve this ?? the current method is giving me a out-of memory exception !!! current code:   (I do not want to use external API or plugins. thanks)

```
MemoryStream ms = ClassB.ToExcel(dt, "Sheet1");
ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename + ".xlsx");
Response.StatusCode = 200;
Response.End();
```

Comment: Probably here you have hit the limits of Excel http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx

Comment: Excel is [limited to 1048576 rows per sheet](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HA103980614.aspx). If you're exporting 5000000+ rows, you'll need to split them into several sheets.

Comment: You might be able to check the limit through code rather than setting an arbitary limit. Try using :
ExcelWorksheet ws = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetName);
int limit = ws.Dimension.End.Row;

Then loop over that to know when to create a new sheet

Comment: The problem is the MemoryStream buffer is getting full and out of memory - there should be a better way of doing this ??

Comment: Anyone else with other options

Comment: Are you sure you are showing the code where the exception occurs? What's going on in ClassB.ToExcel?